# Natural isomorphism: example

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}=Ring_1$ and $\mathcal{D}=Sets$. Define $\mathcal{F}(R)=SL_2(R)$.  Let $A=\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d]/(ad-bc-1)$ .I have to prove that this functor is representable.

If we define $\eta: \mathcal{H}_A \to \mathcal{F}$ such that $\eta_R (\phi)$ is the matrix with entries $\phi$ of the elements, then the diagram commutes:
 $ \eta_P \circ \mathcal{H}_A (f) = \mathcal{F} \circ \eta_R$ where $f:R \to P$ is a $\mathcal{C}$-morphism.

1) I haven't used the definition of $A$ (is it neccesary?)

2) How can I prove that $\eta_R$ is an isomorphism for each $R$?

Comment: This is a small hint: A map from $\mathbb Z[X_1,...,X_n] \rightarrow R$ is uniquely determined by the images of $X_1,..,X_n$.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that $\eta$ is well-defined?  You need to know that for any $\phi:A\to R$, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \phi(a) & \phi(b) \\ \phi(c) & \phi(d)\end{pmatrix}$ is an element of $\mathcal{F}(R)$.  To prove this, you will have to use something about the definition of $A$.

You will also have to use the definition of $A$ to prove that $\eta_R$ is an isomorphism (i.e., a bijection) for each $R$.  To show this, given an element $x=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{F}(R)$, you want to know that there is exactly one homomorphism $\phi:A\to R$ such that $\eta_R(\phi)=x$.  Recalling the definition of $\eta$, the equation $\eta_R(\phi)=x$ just means that $\phi(a)=\alpha$, $\phi(b)=\beta$, $\phi(c)=\gamma$, and $\phi(d)=\delta$.  Can you use the definition of $A$ to prove that for any $x\in \mathcal{F}(R)$, there is a unique homomorphism $\phi:A\to R$ satisfying these equations?